# Link the page numbers in the table of contents with pages

Tags: pdf

How could I link page numbers in the table of content of a pdf file with the pages? I would like to do it with a **single** operation.

For example, in the table of contents I have:

Page 1

Page 2

Page 3

and after there are the pages. When I click on a number, I want to go to the corresponding page.

This is the file (I created a word file and then a pdf file):

http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=09259671722379859014

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello Gennaro. Please Refer this video. [Watch now](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IR7FT3Pr4a0)

Comment: Hi @Techie Gossip, I've seen that. It need to do much operations, not only one.

Comment: How are you creating the PDF? Your original authoring tool would/should provide some support with his. What tool are you using?

Comment: Hi @Seth I edited my question.

Comment: If you originally wrote the file using Word, did you setup the reference in the word file? So does clicking on a toc entry get you to the heading within the word file? If so you might need to check your PDF creation settings. Did you use a third party tool to convert the word file to PDF or did you use the built in converter (at least available on Office 2016)?

Comment: @Seth I used Word+Nitro pro....I have not reference (see the file word that I attached).

Comment: With the file you provided you would either need to manually add references or use the header formatting and a toc.

Comment: Good morning Seth, could you give me a simple example by posting a file.doc please?